# Improve performance in two `OR` condition `mySQL` query

Tags: mysql, performance

I use `MySQL` with `InnoDB` engine.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `video` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `videoId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_video_tags_idx` (`videoId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_video_tags`
    FOREIGN KEY (`videoId`)
    REFERENCES `video` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The `video` table have ~500,000 and `tags` ~400,000 records.

I write a simple query be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `video`
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON (video.id = tags.videoId)
WHERE video.id='1' OR tags.id='1'
```

It's important for me use two condition with `OR` operation.

The `id` field in `WHERE` is just for sample query and I don't sure about numbers of results records so I can not and do not want use `LIMIT`.

This query execution time is ~3 sec. That's bad, But when the situation is worse, That the `tags` table have ~5,000,000 records! In this case execution time was ~160 sec! That's very bad.

So, What's your solution for improve execution time, and improving performance?

Comment: Do you have any try and result for both of these two Answers? @nabi-k-a-z

Comment: @MohaMad Thanks, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes like to break the `OR` into different `SELECT`s and `UNION` the results.

By default, `UNION` has an implicit `DISTINCT` when result sets are combined.

If this doesn't get your speed down enough, then you can run each half individually and see what the absolute minimum time could be. (for each half of the data)

```
SELECT *
FROM `video`
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON (video.id = tags.videoId)
WHERE video.id='1'

UNION

SELECT *
FROM `video`
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON (video.id = tags.videoId)
WHERE tags.id='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting potentially useful tags and store them in mytags temporary table and join this one instead of huge tag table :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `video`
 JOIN 
 ( SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id=1 or videoid=1) as mytags -- (*)
 ON (video.id = mytags.videoId)
```

(*) **Note**:
Where Joining tables on `video.id = tags.videoId` condition and setting `WHERE` condition `video.id='1' OR tags.id='1'` it means selecting tags which matches ( `video.id = 1 = tags.videoId` ) `OR` `tags.id=1` conditions. So I suggest `SELECT` them first and JOIN new minified tags table.

Comment: And if we want to compare on `video.title`, that means: `tags.id='1' OR video.title='1'` ?
In this case, the `title` field there are in `video` table and there are not in `tags` table.